# Which layout have to use

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I am new to android app development.I am developing an android app which is having a design like the following one.Which layout I have to use.If I use Linear layout I cannot place "Product Amount" Textview and Editbox in a stright line.Please help me to solve this. [image]

Comment: please show code that you use (xml)
you can try to use "RelativeLayout":http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this using Linear Layout also
Try below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Product Amount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>





<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

     <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

     <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

 </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

     <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

     <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

See below it's give me output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use more than one layout. Your xml will be something like this.

Linear Layout main (Vertical)
      Linear Layout1 (Horizontal) - for first row.
      Layout 1 ends
      Linear Layout2 (Horizontal) - for second row.
      Layout 2 ends
      Linear Layout3 (Horizontal) - for third row.
      Layout 3 ends
      Text Sale Amt
Layout main ends

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameedt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pwd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pwdedt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/pwdhint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="PasswordHint : HINT" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use TableLayout, with First Row Having four columns, use col span to extend a column for two columns, add View, where Cell isnt exist.